# Reading zipped ESRI BIL files with Python

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, digital-image-processing, band-interleaved-by-line

I asked the question below on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23816545/698809), but haven't received any feedback there yet:

I have precipitation data from the [PRISM Climate Group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23816545/698809) which are now offered in .bil format (ESRI BIL, I think)  and I'd like to be able to read these datasets with Python.

I've installed the [spectral](http://www.spectralpython.net/) package, but the `open_image()` method returns an error:

```
def ReadBilFile(bil):
    import spectral as sp
    b = sp.open_image(bil)
ReadBilFile(r'G:\truncated\ppt\1950\PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_1950_bil.bil')
```

`IOError: Unable to determine file type or type not supported.`

The documentation for spectral clearly says that it supports BIL files, can anyone shed any light on what's happening here? I am also open to using GDAL, which supposedly supports the similar/equivalent ESRI EHdr format, but I can't find any good code snipets to get started.

Comment: Hi Jason. I see that you've got a solution based on GDAL, nice one! For ESRI BIL/BSQ files you can access without GDAL, just flat binary IO. Have a look at this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96050/how-do-i-convert-coordinates-to-raster-bsq-bil-lookup/96067#96067 . I admit that binary IO in python isn't for the faint hearted but it might serve you in the future when you want to get/save individual pixels.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: An explanation of the reason for this error is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816545/reading-zipped-esri-bil-files-with-python/24265784#24265784).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I'm sorry to post a question and then answer it myself so quickly, but I found a nice set of course slides from [Utah State University](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides4.pdf) that has a lecture on opening raster image data with GDAL. For the record, here is the code I used to open the PRISM Climate Group datasets (which are in the EHdr format).

```
def ReadBilFile(bil):
    import gdal
    gdal.GetDriverByName('EHdr').Register()
    img = gdal.Open(bil)
    band = img.GetRasterBand(1)
    data = band.ReadAsArray()
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ReadBilFile(r'G:\truncated\ppt\1950\PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_1950_bil.bil')
    print a[44, 565]
```

EDIT 5/27/2014

I've built upon my answer above and wanted to share it here since the documentation seems to be lacking. I now have a class with one main method that reads the BIL file as an array and returns some key attributes.

```
class BilFile(object):

    def __init__(self, bil_file):
        self.bil_file = bil_file
        self.hdr_file = bil_file.split('.')[0]+'.hdr'

    def get_array(self, mask=None):
        import gdal
        import gdalconst
        self.nodatavalue, self.data = None, None
        gdal.GetDriverByName('EHdr').Register()
        img = gdal.Open(self.bil_file, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
        band = img.GetRasterBand(1)
        self.nodatavalue = band.GetNoDataValue()
        self.ncol = img.RasterXSize
        self.nrow = img.RasterYSize
        geotransform = img.GetGeoTransform()
        self.originX = geotransform[0]
        self.originY = geotransform[3]
        self.pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
        self.pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
        self.data = band.ReadAsArray()
        self.data = np.ma.masked_where(self.data==self.nodatavalue, self.data)
        if mask is not None:
            self.data = np.ma.masked_where(mask==True, self.data)
        return self.nodatavalue, self.data
```

I call this class using the following function where I use GDAL's vsizip function to [read the BIL file directly from a zip file](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/ReadInZip).

```
import prism
def getPrecipData(years=None):
    grid_pnts = prism.getGridPointsFromTxt()
    flrd_pnts = np.array(pd.read_csv(r'D:\truncated\PrismGridPointsFlrd.csv').grid_code)
    mask = prism.makeGridMask(grid_pnts, grid_codes=flrd_pnts)
    for year in years:
        bil = r'/vsizip/G:\truncated\PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_{0}_all_bil.zip\PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_{0}_bil.bil'.format(year)
        b = prism.BilFile(bil)
        nodatavalue, data = b.get_array(mask=mask)
        data *= mm_to_in
        b.write_to_csv(data, 'PrismPrecip_{}.txt'.format(year))
    return

# Get datasets
years = range(1950, 2011, 5)
getPrecipData(years=years)
```

Comment: It looks like in newer versions of GDAL you should use gdal.OpenEx instead: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218471/123816