# Unable to open folder.gdb with OpenFileGDB driver in GDAL

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase

I have upgraded to GDAL 2.1 on Windows, binaries from: http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-gdal-2-1-2-mapserver-7-0-2.zip

I am able to use the command line:

`> ogrinfo -al "C:/path/to/my/folder.gdb"`

and it works fine, giving me details of the contents.

However, from my C code:

```
 GDALDatasetH dataset = GDALOpen( "C:/path/to/my/folder.gdb", GA_ReadOnly );
```

I get back NULL, and the console says:

```
  ERROR 4: `C:/path/to/my/folder.gdb' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Yet I am still able to successfully open other files with GDALOpen(), such as .tiff, .sid, and others (all rasters, this is the first time I'm trying to open a vector file). Further, when I use GDALGetDriverCount() and GDALGetDriver(), and print the short and long name of each driver, I get a list of 200 drivers, including:

```
159 ESRI Personal GeoDatabase -- PGeo
160 MySQL -- MySQL
161 ESRI FileGDB -- OpenFileGDB
```

At one point I was including ogr_FileGDB.dll in my plugins directory, and that was giving a .dll load error on GDALAllRegister() because I don't have the Esri GDB SDK .dlls. But I thought maybe just having ogr_FileGDB.dll in the plugins directory was confusing GDAL and that's why the OpenFileGDB driver wasn't working. But even after removing ogr_FileGDB.dll from the plugins directory, I still get NULL when opening the .gdb.

Any ideas for how I can figure out what's going on?

Comment: The "OpenFileGDB" driver doesn't have *anything* to do with Esri's file geodatabase DLL.

Comment: Well, if I had the Ersi SDK installed and both the FileGDB driver and the OpenFileGDB driver got registered, and then I opened a .gdb folder, presumably one of those drivers would chosen to open the dataset, in preference to the other, so in that way they do have *something* to do with each other, right?

Comment: No, GDAL would have something to do with each of them. Directionality is important. A->B and A->C does not imply B->C or C->B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR Use [`GDALOpenEx`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#aca05455472359964151f9c891d678d5e)

GDAL can only read vector data from File GDBs* and the [`GDALOpen`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a6836f0f810396c5e45622c8ef94624d4) method is for raster data. This is why you get `ERROR 4: 'C:/path/to/my/folder.gdb' not recognized as a supported file format.`.

* Raster support was added to the OpenFileGDB driver in GDAL version 3.7

In GDAL 1.X you would use [`OGROpen`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__api_8h.html#a2da3630231780d519543d1679c83e62f) to open vector data.

In GDAL 2.X you can still use `OGROpen` to open vector data and `GDALOpen` to open raster data but note that both methods are deprecated in favour of the unified method [`GDALOpenEx`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#aca05455472359964151f9c891d678d5e).

Comment: More info https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc46_gdal_ogr_unification

Comment: To clarify, I had a comment that they should rename the functions to make it more clear, but deleted it because I realized that made no sense since it would break existing code, as Luke replied.