# Simple gdal coordinate conversion

Tags: gdal

Starting with an `.img` file how to I convert a specific (x,y) coordinate into (lon,lat) with `gdal`. I don't know what my input format is, but if I type `gdalinfo topo.img` it tells me the corner coordinates of the map, so it ought to be possible to get the coordinates for any of the grid points without further input. `gdallocationinfo topo.img [x] [y]` gives the elevation only.

The beginning of the `gdalinfo` output for the input file looks like this:

`Driver: HFA/Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
Files: bigislandDTM.img
       bigislandDTM.ige
       bigislandDTM.rrd
Size is 32609, 35573
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_5N",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-153],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26905"]]
Origin = (170717.059624216170050,2247879.339183096773922)
Pixel Size = (4.497066284309543,-4.497066284309542)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  170717.060, 2247879.339) (156d 9' 9.63"W, 20d18' 1.76"N)
Lower Left  (  170717.060, 2087905.200) (156d 7'28.87"W, 18d51'25.08"N)
Upper Right (  317361.894, 2247879.339) (154d44'57.59"W, 20d19'12.58"N)
Lower Right (  317361.894, 2087905.200) (154d44' 1.61"W, 18d52'30.47"N)
Center      (  244039.477, 2167892.270) (155d26'24.29"W, 19d35'22.45"N)`

Comment: Are you programming or just trying to work out where on the image a coordinate is to go to it? I have already answered this question before for programming, if that is what you're after have a look here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96050/how-do-i-convert-coordinates-to-raster-bsq-bil-lookup/96067#96067 but it's important that your query point and your raster are in the same coordinate system if they're not that's a different matter but can be solved with proj lib that comes with GDAL.

Comment: I need to make a topo map. I have successfully cropped out and downsampled a region from a giant `img` file with `gdal_translate -of xyz -srcwin 12000 11000 7000 2000 -outsize 22.49% 22.49% topo.img tmp.txt`. If I can get the corner coordinates of what I have cropped out, then I know how to make a topo map with GMT.

In the example you link, it is assumed that x and longitude are related linearly, which is not exactly true if I look at the corner coordinates of my rectangular grid.

Comment: Are your image and query coordinates in a different spatial reference (for example you have Geographic lat/lon and your image is in metres UTM)? If you can tell me what programming/scripting languages you have available I can walk you through projecting coordinates otherwise use GDALwarp to transform your image from one spatial reference to another such that query and image are the same.

Comment: I am doing this on a Linux prompt, but could as well write a shell script.
I added information about my input file above. I had also tried `img2grd`, but can't get it to produce any output. Thanks!

Comment: So what's an example of your sample point? I get the feeling that you want to convert a coordinate like  -122 36 00, 33 15 00 (-122.6E 33.25N) and get the cell value. Your raster is in Metres (NAD 1983 UTM Zone 5) so you would need to project the coordinate or the raster to the same, you can project a coordinate in a python script using GDAL or project a raster using GDAL_Warp... projecting a coordinate would be much quicker for one instance but if you've got a lot of lookups to do then projecting the raster might be the way to go.

Comment: Why don't you just crop out to something that will maintain the metadata (e.g. GeoTiff), then you can just get it from `gdalinfo output_file.tif`

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very simple python script using GDAL (well, OGR and OSR which are part of the GDAL package) to project a coordinate from one spatial reference to another:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr

InSR = osr.SpatialReference()
InSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326)       # WGS84/Geographic
OutSR = osr.SpatialReference()
OutSR.ImportFromEPSG(32756)     # WGS84 UTM Zone 56 South

Point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
Point.AddPoint(150.700532,-35.145618) # use your coordinates here
Point.AssignSpatialReference(InSR)    # tell the point what coordinates it's in
Point.TransformTo(OutSR)              # project it to the out spatial reference
print '{0},{1}'.format(Point.GetX(),Point.GetY()) # output projected X and Y coordinates
```

output: 290523.025428,6108387.72056

The values here are hard coded to show an example of how to convert from one to another but it shouldn't be too difficult to modify to suit your needs. You already have GDAL installed and probably have python.. if not GDAL/OGR/OSR is available in many more languages but is fundamentally the same process.

Comment: thank god lol...pyproj is apparently a nightmare and this worked just great